# AttributeError: 'SMOTE' object has no attribute 'fit_sample'

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, attributeerror, imblearn

Why I am getting the error

```
AttributeError: 'SMOTE' object has no attribute 'fit_sample'
```

I don't think this code should cause any error?

```py
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
smt = SMOTE(random_state=0)
X_train_SMOTE, y_train_SMOTE = smt.fit_sample(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: It's called `fit_resample`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you import like this

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
```

you need to do `fit_resample()`

```
oversample = SMOTE()
X, y = oversample.fit_resample(X, y)
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for responding, but may I ask is fit_sample() and fit_resample() is the same? Because I am actually following some tutorial when I face this error and they write fit_sample(). Many Thanks

Comment: Probably this tutorial: https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-logistic-regression-in-python-step-by-step-becd4d56c9c8 - Landed here because their code has this error.

Comment: Precisely, lol, this is exactly why I got here too.

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
from imblearn.combine import SMOTEENN

Sm=SMOTEENN()
X, y=Sm.fit_resample(X, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

It used to be `fit_sample` but was renamed `fit_resample` with an alias for backward compatibility in imblearn 0.4 ([this was documented](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html#id30)). Then the alias was [removed in version 0.8](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/commit/a9e1121f4f00ea9bee2b5a5c1e6ffb661d423ede) (for some reason it was not documented). In short, `SMOTE().fit_sample(X_train, y_train)` used to work but not anymore.

Now only `SMOTE().fit_resample(X_train, y_train)` works.

Also, all imblearn objects have a `fit()` method defined as well but it's completely useless because everything it does is already done by `fit_resample()` anyway (the documentation even urges you to use `fit_resample()` over `fit()`).